# C# - UWP: Load different view in one base views

Tags: c#, xaml, view, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am a software developer student and for my schoolproject I am searching for the solution for loading different **Views** in an *Base*view.
I got an UWP application, that runs on a Raspberry Pi.
For my application I need te navigatie between two users (regular- and expert user).

**So what is my question?** 

*How to switch between the two users, but without reload views(pages)?*

 The views cannot refresh because the content is real-time and has to run also when you switch between user views.

It is a C# Uwp application.
For now I have the files:

- BaseView.xaml (this is the (main)view where I want to load Aview or Bview)
- AView.xaml
- BView.xaml

Maby someone can help me with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place a ContentPresenter into your BaseView.
Then wrap your AView and BView into data templates. Now you can use a converter to select a template your ContentPresenter shows.

```
<Page>
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AViewTemplate">
            <views:AView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="BViewTemplate">
            <views:BView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <conv:ModeToTemplateConverter ATemplate="{StaticResource AViewTemplate}" BTemplate="{StaticResource BViewTemplate}" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding YourViewModel}" 
                      ContentTemplate="{Binding Mode, Converter={StaticResource ModeToTemplateConverter}}" />
</Page>
```

The converter can be like that:

```
    public class ModeToTemplateConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public DataTemplate ATemplate { get; set; }

        public DataTemplate BTemplate { get; set; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var mode = value as Mode?;
            switch (mode)
            {
                case Mode.A:
                    return ATemplate;
                case Mode.B:
                    return BTemplate;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have both views as per your need in your BaseView.xaml file. There you maintain 2 grids - one for AView and the another one for BView and then finally based on your user criteria you hide/show the visibility of both the grids.

Cheers!